# What's wrong with my R plots produced by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, r, osx-snow-leopard

I've been using the Stat/ET Eclipse R Combo for quite a while and I am happy with it. Though lately plots behave strange. If I plot something, plots open in a Quartz window (which is fine). But I can neither resize it nor close it (except if I force it to close). The task manager just labels these open quartz windows "java".

I havent had this issue before, probably I just happened after my Eclipse update to helios. Maybe I just missed some setting that I had before.

a) has anyone an idea how to fix this ?

b) how can I set the default plot to X11 plotting to circumvent the whole issue until i found a solution?

Eclipse Helios, R 2.12, Mac OS X 10.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this too (Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.1; OS X 10.6.6, x86_64). You can get round it by running X11:

```
X11()
```

or, I typically use Cairo:

```
library(Cairo) 
Cairo(X11)
```

Comment: Is there a way to set X11() as default?

Comment: Can you place this in .Rprofile? I'm a relative beginner so I don't use .Rprofile as yet but see elsewhere in stackoverflow: search ˚Startup [r]˚ or ˚.Rprofile [r]˚.